Different loot table for naturally spawned/summoned Vindicator
I'm trying to see a bug that occurs in certain mobs when they have an enchanted item in v1.16.1, but I just realized that the loot table for summoned vindicators with:
/summon minecraft:vindicator ~ ~2 ~

Only give drops of axes with Silk Touch, Fortune, Efficiency or Unbreaking, never Sharpness, unlike if the vindicator was spawned naturally (outpost/raid), where they can drop axes with that enchantment. Is there a command to generate it with its "natural loot table," or does anyone know why this happens?
Another thing I tried was to create a mob spawner for vindicators, but in this case, they only drop emeralds, no axes.
I really wouldn't want to have to create a raid farm just to be able to do my tests.

Axes actually don't show up in a Vindicator's loot table at all, as they come from a separate system:
When a Vindicator drops an axe, that's the axe that it was holding. Like most equipment that mobs spawn wearing/holding, the axe in a Vindicator's hand has an 8.5% chance of dropping when the Vindicator is killed by a player.
Under normal circumstances (spawned from a command, spawned in a woodland mansion, etc.) a Vindicator's axe may spawn with a random axe-related enchantment, as you identified. The exception is when a Vindicator is spawned as part of a raid. Raid Vindicators don't get the random axe enchantment, and instead have a chance (based on the strength of the raid) to get Sharpness.



Bad Omen level
Chance of Sharpness




I
0%


II
10%


III
25%


IV
50%


V
75%



This will be Sharpness I in waves 1-5 and Sharpness II in waves 6 and up.
So if you want a mansion-like Vindicator, you already have one. If you just want a Vindicator with a Sharpness axe, that's pretty easy:
/summon minecraft:vindicator ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_axe",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:1s}]}},{}]}

If you want to fully simulate the loot chances of a raid-like Vindicator, you'll need something more complicated that takes inputs for Bad Omen level and wave number.
